# Why does pandas df show tsv's mandatory trailing-newline from pd.read_csv() as NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, trailing-newline

My programming professor and the [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline) say I **must always** append **exactly one** empty line (=trailing newline) to all my output text files.

Why does

`my_df = pd.read_csv('my.tsv', delimiter='\t', skip_blank_lines=True)`

still read this `\n` into my pandas data frames and fills it with `NaN` values?

So far I have used `df_no_nan = df.dropna(how="any", inplace=False)`.

[image]

What am I missing?

Is there a better solution?

Here the `WeTransfer` link to the file:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d34deac70e33a0a6351b8e4d6b4e3b8720210602143836/74fa00

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this behavior. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, I've edited the post and added the exact file I'm using. The link will expire in 7 days.

Comment: I think you may be confusing yourself a little with the interpretation of the rule - it's that files are supposed to end with a `\n` that terminates the last line of the file, not that they need to end with a completely blank line (i.e., `\n\n`).

Comment: @Randy indeed, I got the file from my supervisor - it had 4 empty lines at the end. I cut 3 of those out - to observe the 'trailing empty line' rule. So you're saying I could have just cut all 4 empty lines that appeared? That is confusing to me as I'm quite sure I was taught to always hit `enter` in vim to add an extra line to each file - from what you say, I take that is wrong too?

Comment: Yeah, that is wrong. vim follows the POSIX standard and will put the `\n` at the end of your last line for you when you save the file. You can check this yourself if you're curious by making a simple one-line file in vim, saving it, and running it through `hexdump`. The last byte will be `0a`, or `\n` in ASCII.